# Losing write access after GIT Merge

Tags: git

Every time I do a `git fetch` / `git merge origin/master`, I lose access to write to the files that have been changed.  I've tried `git config --add --global core.filemode false` to no avail.  Any other ideas floating around out there?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "lose access to write"? Do you get some error or how does this occur?

Comment: When I go to open that file that I pulled down from GitHub, make a change, and save the file, I get access denied.

Comment: Assuming you're running some flavour of Linux, sounds like it could be file permissions - what user is git running as, and are they in the same group as your user? Are there any different permissions on the files that are written after the fetch?

Comment: which operating system you are using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Comment: Are you using `sudo` when performing those `git fetch/merge` commands?

Comment: Yes, without it, it denies me permission to git fetch/merge

Comment: There you have your issue. Reclone the repo with normal user rights.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the user are pushing with doesn't have write permission for that directory